# Connecting a Matlab Neural Network with a VB.NET program

Tags: vb.net, matlab, neural-network

I developed a neural network to train for face detection of the extracted images. However my program is built on VB.NET and I need to know the techniques by which I could load this neural network (Exported using NNTOOL) into memory and call it from VB.NET

So far I was only able to find this,

```
Dim MatLab As Object
Dim Result As String
Dim MReal(1, 3) As Double
Dim MImag(1, 3) As Double
Dim RealValue As Double
MatLab = CreateObject("matlab.application")
Result = MatLab.Execute("a = [1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8;]")
Call MatLab.GetFullMatrix("a", "base", MReal, MImag)
```

I do not quite understand how this works, any suggestions on whether I could conenct the Neural network to VB.NET using this code and if so could you please explain to me about the Matlab.Execute and Matlab.GetFullMatrix functions. (What arguements would it support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[In this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/matlabeng.aspx), three possible solutions are described. If you don't care much about performance, go with the first solution (use COM interop). Else, go with the third option (PInvoke), which is the fastest one. If you do choose to use PInvoke, a great resource is [PInvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/)